# Relative stability of sums of i.i.d. non-negative random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the following are equivalent for i.i.d. non-negative random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$

a) There exist constants $a_n>0$ such that $$a_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\xrightarrow{P} 1.$$

b)As $n\rightarrow\infty$ $$\frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{X_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}\xrightarrow{P} 0.$$

c) We have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{E(X_1 1_{\{X_1\leq x\}})}{xP(X_1>x)}=\infty$$

d) We have that the function $\mu(x):=E(X_1 1_{\{X_1\leq x\}})$ is slowly varying; that is, $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu(tx)}{\mu(t)}=1$$ for all $x>0.$

To prove a) implies b) is enough to prove that $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{X_i}/n$ converges in probability to $0,$ then we have the desire result.

To prove b) implies c) I have some problems; because of b) we can conclude that $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{X_i}/n$ converges to zero in probability, which is equivalent to $xP(X_1>x)$ converges to $0.$ Then, for WLLN we have $\frac{S_n}{n}-E(X_1 1_{\{X_1\leq n\}})\xrightarrow{P}0$ but I cannot ensure such limit.

To prove c) implies d) and d) imlies a) I have problems finding a good path to prove them.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.